# Android video player custom control panel

Tags: android, video, progress-bar, android-mediaplayer

In my app, I have a video player. There is a custom control panel for that. I have implemented play, pause, stop functionality using the [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) class. Now I want to add a progress bar in that control panel. How can I implement that? Can anyone give me any sample code or idea for the same?

Comment: But MediaController class itself will have its own Progress bar, right?!

Comment: I do want the in build control panel. The UI of it does not match with requirement, because its looks different and does not go with the theme of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SeekBar.
Then find the total length of your media, and set that as the max value.
Update this SeekBar on a regular interval as the media plays along - for example every 5th second - depending on the media length. (Interval would have to be shorter if the media file is short).